# Removing rows from a data frame when the value In a specific column is less than the previous value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple rows.  Before I can produce plots I must perform filtering on the time column. Typically the value for time will increase at a 1Hz rate however there will be cases when the value for time will go backward. I need to drop any rows that have those "invalid" values for time.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
df = pd.concat([df[:1],df[df.shift(1)['time'] < df['time']]])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a DF with a time column (or some other numeric representation of time):

```
DF=pd.DataFrame({'Time':[1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6]})
```

With pandas use the `diff` method to find negative rows (i.e. rows where the next time value is less), which are then filtered out:

```
DF[DF.Time.diff()>=0]
```

`True` values in the DF are retained.

Comment: If the dtype of the column is datetime `diff` should still work, IMO this is the correct answer